# Editing a duplicate list edits the original

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

So I've started a simple sort of roguelike game project in python, but I have problems with editing a duplicate list editing the original. The code is as follows:

```
charx = 1
chary = 1
level = [["#","#","#","#","#","#","#"],["#",".",".",".",".",".","#"],["#",".","#",".",".",".","#"],["#","#","#","#","#","#","#"]]
while True:
    move = raw_input("u,d,l or r: ")
    if move=="u":
        if level[chary-1][charx]!="#":
            chary-=1
    elif move=="d":
        if level[chary+1][charx]!="#":
            chary+=1
    elif move=="r":
        if level[chary][charx+1]!="#":
            charx+=1
    elif move=="l":
        if level[chary][charx-1]!="#":
            charx-=1
    display_level=level
    display_level[chary][charx]="@"
    for row in display_level:
        print "".join(row)
    for row2 in level:
        print ",".join(row2)
```

As you can see I have created list called level, where each list inside the list is a row. The characters starting row and column position is stated.

Then the loop asks whether you want to move up, down left or right. It checks to see if there is a wall (the # character) in the way and reacts accordingly.

As you can see, it makes a duplicate of the level called display_level and then puts an "@" as the character onto display level. The problem is however is that changing display_level changes level as well for no apparent reason, even though they are separate and each time the loop runs through it makes display_level=level.

display_level and level are then printed separately and it shows level being edited along side display_level which shouldn't happen.

So what I want to know is why changing an part of display_level would change level and how I can fix it.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *not* creating a duplicate of `level`. All you do is create another reference to the *same list*.

To create a copy of a list, you can just slice it from start to end:

```
display_level = level[:]
```

but for your case, that is *not enough*. You need to copy the *nested* lists. In this case, a list comprehension is easiest:

```
display_level = [l[:] for l in level]
```

A more comprehensive solution is to use the [`copy.deepcopy()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to make *absolutely sure* that the top-level object and all contained objects are copies:

```
import copy

# ...

display_level = copy.deepcopy(level)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your explanation makes it clear. Thanks to all of you for the fast replies.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a variable to another is referencing not duplicating. Use [`copy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) instead.

```
>>> l = range(10)                    # assign original list
>>> l                                # display list (l)   
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a = l                            # assign a to l
>>> a                                # display list (a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a.remove(4)                      # remove '4' item from a
>>> a                                # display list (a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]          # notice that '4' is gone   
>>> l                                # display list (l)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]          # notice that '4' is *also* gone   
>>> import copy                      # import the copy module
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(l)             # create a deepcopy of l called b
>>> b                                # display list (b)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]          # notice, '4' is still gone.
>>> l                                # display list (l)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]          
>>> b.remove(3)                      # remove '3' item from b
>>> b                                # display list (b)   
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]             # notice, '3' is gone. 
>>> l                                # display list (l)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]          # notice, '3' is still there.
```

**note:** there are some "simpler" ways, or "shortcuts" to copying lists detailed in [Martijn's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17704107/1561176)

Comment: `copy.copy()` is overkill when a `list()` call or an identity slice (`level[:]`) will do.

Comment: Besides, you need a *deep* copy, not a shallow copy.

Comment: After putting import copy at the top and changing:
display_level=level
to
display_level=copy.copy(level)
The problem persists. Any ideas? In the meantime i'll try Martijin's suggestion.

Comment: Ok I tried display_level=list(level) and display_level=level[:] in place of display_level=level but the problem persists. Any ideas?

Comment: @FraserHislop Can not know without being able to see the code in action. Regardless, *this* is how to duplicate a list. Other problems with your code should be asked in a new question.

Comment: Well that's all of the code, so copy pasting it into http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace should give you an idea.

Comment: I am sorry that your code is not working, but this question was about how to duplicate (copy) a list correctly, the answers provided here do just that. If you have further problems with your code, you should try asking another question. I can assure you that if you use any of these proper solutions, your list is being copied correctly, and the problem in your code is somewhere else.

Comment: Nevermind, Martijin and jh314 answered my question. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: I think the problem is that you used the regular `copy()` instead of `deepcopy()`

Answer (score 1):

You should make a new copy of the list of list by doing this:

```
display_level=[l[:] for l in level]
```

instead of this:

```
display_level=level
```

Otherwise, you have two references to the same list, rather than two separate lists.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Also, would you be able to explain to me why making a copy of the list using display_list=list(level) or display_list=level[:] as suggested above didn't work? Also I'm not entirely sure how display_level=[l[:] for l in level] works, much appreciated.

Comment: Ah nevermind, Martijin answered it in his other comment, thank you very much though.